# reactjs es6 calling function inside other function throws function not defined

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

[Here is my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-saga-example-fhr31?from-embed)

In App.js file there is a button component. I am calling hi function onclick event. In this event, I want to use redux saga to call sayHello();

if I am using sayHello directly on button click event, code works fine. But my requirement is call it in an other function. Below is the entire file for reference.Appreciate your help.

Comment: class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const { hello, sayHello} = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello {hello}</h1>
        <h2>Redux-saga demo. Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        <button onClick={hi}>Say Hello!</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const hi = () => {
  console.log("hiiiiiiiiii");
  sayHello();
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  hello: state.hello
});
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  sayHello: actions.sayHello,
};
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);

Comment: That's because in `mapDispatchToProps` you're attaching the `sayHello` action to the App component's props, so it's available that way inside the component (i.e. `this.props.sayHello`). Inside your `hi` function, `sayHello` isn't defined anywhere. So I'm guessing you'd have to reference it directly, e.g. `actions.sayHello()`. Disclaimer: I haven't used saga before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should defined ur function in your component scope.

Because the function `SayHello` is defined in `props`.

Just like this:

```
class App extends Component {

  hi = () => {
    onsole.log("hiiiiiiiiiiiiii");
    this.props.sayHello();
  }

  render() {
    const { hello, exampleTask } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello {hello}</h1>
        <h2>Redux-saga demo. Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        <button onClick={this.hi}>Say Hello!</button>
        <button onClick={exampleTask}>Example Task</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When calling some function in another function, you have to specify the scope.
Use it as below:

```
const hi = () => {
 console.log("hiiiiiiiiiiiiii");
 this.sayHello();
};
```

Hope this helps!